# Why my testing function in the Django returns status code 404 while the page is shown correctly in the chrome browser?

Tags: python, django, testing, http-status-code-404

I am a Django novice and I am trying to proceed with a simple application testing and I follow a tutorial (simpleisbetterthancomplex). One of the tests fails but I cannot find the reason why. I added several prints to clear what was going on.

The test function that fails is:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.urls import resolve
from django.test import TestCase
from .views import home, board_topics
from .models import Board

# some code here

class BoardTopicsTests(TestCase):
#....
    def test_board_topics_view_contains_navigation_links(self):
        board_topics_url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': 1})
        print("49: board_topic = " + board_topics_url)
        homepage_url = reverse('home')
        print("51: homepage_url = " + homepage_url)
        new_topic_url = reverse('new_topic', kwargs={'pk': 1})
        print("53: new_topic_url = " + new_topic_url)
        response = self.client.get(board_topics_url)
        print("*****************\n")
        print(response)
        print('********************\n')
        self.assertContains(response, 'href="{0}"'.format(homepage_url))
        self.assertContains(response, 'href="{0}"'.format(new_topic_url))
#...
```

Then I can see the output:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.49: board_topic = /boards/1/
51: homepage_url = /
53: new_topic_url = /boards/1/new/
*****************

<HttpResponseNotFound status_code=404, "text/html">
********************
```

It looks like board_topics_url is not working. But in my chrome explorer it works very good and returns a page with both links homepage_url = '/' and new_topic_url = '/boards/1/new/':

```
 ...      
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Boards</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Django</li>
      </ol>

    <div class="mb-4">
        <a href="/boards/1/new/" class="btn btn-primary">New topic</a>
    </div>
...
```

Both links are working correctly.

Please, any idea what could be wrong? Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you create a `Board` (or whatever your model name is) instance first - before reaching `reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': 1})`?

Comment: Hi Pedram. Thank you for your interest. I have defined the class Board within models.py file where it should be correctly iniciated. The procedure above (def test_board_topics_view_contains_navigation_links(self):) is part of the test.py file and I just call "py manage.py test" (in windows). Within the test I believe the request is sent using "self.client.get(board_topics_url)" and stored to the response. The response is however the 404 status failure. If I request 127.0.0.1.:8000//boards/1/ in my browser it shows up correctly.

Comment: So you didn't really answer my question; just to clarify it more, django create an **empty** database for your tests, so need to create objects (a `Board` object in your case) _before_ testing it. Are you taking account for that?

Comment: I believe I should have one record since I have 
'class BoardTopicsTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Board.objects.create(name='First', description='First board.')
'
OK?

Answer (score 0):

During several tests sample record was repeatedly created and deleted. Therefore the id was not 1 but some higher number. A detection of the ID of current record solved the issue:

```
    def test_board_topics_view_contains_navigation_links(self):
        boards_list = Board.objects.all()        #### added line
        board_topics_url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': boards_list[0].id}) ### replaced 1 by boards_list[0].id
        homepage_url = reverse('home')
        new_topic_url = reverse('new_topic', kwargs={'pk': boards_list[0].id})  ### replaced 1 by boards_list[0].id
        response = self.client.get(board_topics_url)
        self.assertContains(response, 'href="{0}"'.format(homepage_url))
        self.assertContains(response, 'href="{0}"'.format(new_topic_url))
```